# Webhook using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, rest, client, webhooks, receiver

We are working on web page which has Java script & HTML now. It invokes Rest API of 3rd party application using Java script. It works well when we call Rest methods like Login & other methods. Question is how this client side will receive events using web hook. 3rd party application pushes / send events at client, but at client end we need to register events & subscribe/listen/receive events. I have done this in .Net using signalR but not sure how this will be implemented in this (Java script ) environment. Any sample would be appreciated.

Comment: You're having another service call a webhook in your code? That's just a normal API.

Comment: the only way to achieve this is to implement a Web socket logic and listen for events.

Comment: In API we call /api/instance/registerWebhook to register webhook and in .Net I do   // subscribe all instance events
                client.EventAdapter.Subscribe(new ISEvent());  How this can be achieved in Java script?